# Bottom overloaded by 213 pixels in flutter

Tags: android, ios, material-design, flutter

Hi I am trying to create login screen. It is working fine for me. When I open the keyboard then it is giving me an error `Bottom overloaded by 213 pixels`.

```
  Widget LoginPage() {
    return new Scaffold(body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        image: DecorationImage(
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05), BlendMode.dstATop),
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/mountains.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(120.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.headset_mic,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "EMAIL",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'samarthagarwal@live.com',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "PASSWORD",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: '*********',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    "Forgot Password?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new FlatButton(
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 20.0,
                        horizontal: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "LOGIN",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 0.25)),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "OR CONNECT WITH",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 0.25)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                          child: new FlatButton(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0Xff3B5998),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            child: new Container(
                              child: new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Expanded(
                                    child: new FlatButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 20.0,
                                        bottom: 20.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: new Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            const IconData(0xea90,
                                                fontFamily: 'icomoon'),
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            size: 15.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "FACEBOOK",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                          child: new FlatButton(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0Xffdb3236),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            child: new Container(
                              child: new Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Expanded(
                                    child: new FlatButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 20.0,
                                        bottom: 20.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: new Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            const IconData(0xea88,
                                                fontFamily: 'icomoon'),
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            size: 15.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "GOOGLE",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 46):

I would suggest replacing the top Column widget with a ListView, that automatically resizes on keyboard input, whilst also supporting scrolling.

If you really want this setup as it is, you can edit your Scaffold with the parameter

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```

That should make the error disappear

Comment: Problem still, :(

Comment: Read the response I posted below, this will not solve the problem

Comment: Perfect!

This a more simple solution in large cases...

Look this movie about this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E9iZgg5TOY

Comment: you can wrap main Column widget with Singlechildscrollview ,This will work even if you have number of textFields.

Comment: You are awesome, replacing "Column" with "ListView" worked for me

Comment: replace Column with ListVIew

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is deprecated or removed from Scafold Widget use the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` with a scrollable widget to wrap your widgets.

Answer (score 44):

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // set it to false
  ... 
)
```

---

As Andrey said, you may have issues with scrolling, so you may try

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // set it to false
  body: SingleChildScrollView(child: YourBody()),
)
```

Answer (score 15):

With `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` in Scaffold, You don't see all the widgets that are below the open textfield. The solution is to insert a container with a SingleChildScrollView inside. Example:

```
Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    color: viewModel.color,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(child:"Your widgets"));
```

Comment: Wrapping the Scaffold body with SingleChildScrollVie Solved the issue. +1

Answer (score 13):

you usually need to provide a scroll widget on top of your widgets because if you try to open the keyboard or change the orientation of your phone, flutter needs to know how to handle the distribution of the widgets on the screen.

Please review this resource, you can check the different options that flutter provide Out of the box, and choose the best option for your scenario.

https://flutter.io/widgets/scrolling/

Comment: I am confused which one I should use ? I want my screen should be scroll as like android has `ScrollView` Can you please suggest?

Comment: It's confusing at first but when you build many pages you can know what widget it is more useful than other, according to the code that you shared, you can use the listView instead Column widget.

Answer (score 10):

wrap your child view into ListView will solve the prob. Please check this

```
 class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
     child: ListView(
       children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

                new Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1,top: 50,right: 1,bottom: 1),
                  child: new Text("jk", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "mono_bold")),
                ),

                 new Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1,top: 50,right: 1,bottom: 1),
                  child: new TextField(
                    style: new TextStyle(),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Email",
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  )
                ),
                 new Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1,top: 50,right: 1,bottom: 1),
                  child: new TextField(
                    style: new TextStyle(

                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Password"

                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    obscureText: true,
                    ),
                ),
              ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

wrap your column into **`SingleChildScrollView`** will solve the problem. Please check this:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(),
              TextField(),
            ],
          ),
        ))));
  }
```

And You also use for removing yellow black overflow line

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```

but in this case, `TextField` does not move up on click time.

Comment: this is okay but my page should not scroll, there will be no textfield.. How we can split two container with 0.5 per height from parent with appBar?

Answer (score 7):

wrap with SingleChildScrollView Widget here's my code to solve this situation:
it is best and easiest method

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Hero(
            tag: 'logo',
                        child: Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 48.0,
          ),
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              //Do something with the user input.
            },
            decoration:  kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter username'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              //Do something with the user input.
            },
            decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter password'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 24.0,
          ),

           RoundedButton(
            colour: Colors.blueAccent,
            text: 'Register',
            onPressed: () {
            //later todo
            },
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` for avoiding overflow, but you can't reach fields in bottom of page, which can be covered by keyboard.

Or you can wrap body of `Scaffold` inside `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose all the widgets within the ListView.
So you can scroll it and the overloaded will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

you should add  **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,** and  put your button in **child:SingleChildScrollView()** like the following code below :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize:const Size(double.infinity,100),
        child:(ResponsiveLayout.isTinyLimit(context) ||
              ResponsiveLayout.isTinyHeightLimit(context))
            ? Container()
            : const AppBarWidget(),
),

  body: Center(
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Padding(

        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

      child: Center(


        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
          children: [
            Text("Temperature"),
            LineChartSample2(),

            Text("Gas Level"),
            LineChartSample2(),
            on?Icon(Icons.lightbulb,
              size:100,
              color: Colors.lightBlue.shade700 ,
            ):const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline,
              size:100,

            ),
              ElevatedButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: on? Colors.green: Colors.white10),
                onPressed: (){
                dbR.child("movement").set({"Switch":!on});
                setState(() {
                  on = !on;
                });
                },
                  child:on ? const Text("On"):const Text("Off"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ) ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: There seems to be some code outside of code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

put this in your Scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your content in to SingleChildScrollView and add a ConstrainedBox and try

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your top column inside `SingleChildScrollView`.

Make you layout scrollable.

Comment: this is okay but my page should not scroll, there will be no textfield.. How we can split two container with 0.5 per height from parent with appBar? –

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Fields in single child `ScrollView` of Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

This align items bottom to top,
Try this..

```
child: SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    reverse: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove unwanted padding top and bottom

```
    child: Container(

          height: size.height,
             width: size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: size.width * 0.15,
              right: size.width * 0.15,
              top: size.width * 0.15,
              bottom: size.width * 0.15,
         ),
```

to change by this

```
     child: Container(
    
              height: size.height,
                 width: size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: size.width * 0.15,
                  right: size.width * 0.15,
             ),
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

please set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false`  and set `scrollPadding` in textField

Answer (score 0):

Instead of column widget try to use flex widget, which might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the container on which you put your email and password text field with a Flexible and SingleChildScrollView widgets

Answer (score 0):

**SingleChildScrollView** only works on top of **Column** widget for me and no need resizeToAvoidBottomInset:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Text('Register'),
    ),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
    child: Center(
      heightFactor: 100,
      child: SingleChildScrollView( // SingleChildScrollView here
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    hintText: 'sample : john2020@gmail.com'),
              ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping your main Column with

1.(ListView and give property shrinkWrap: true,) List view has property  children: [], or

2.( SingleChildScrollView() )but it has only child: , .

Something like:

```
 child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: <Widget>[
                new Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(120.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.headset_mic,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                          child: new Text(
                            "EMAIL",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            width: 0.5,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid),
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            obscureText: true,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'samarthagarwal@live.com',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 24.0,
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                          child: new Text(
                            "PASSWORD",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            width: 0.5,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid),
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            obscureText: true,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: '*********',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ])
              ]),
```