# how to resolve BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 84 PIXLES in Flutter Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter I have the following activity, when I click in Text Field Keyboard appears and then the  `warning` e.g. `BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 84 PIXLES`  also appears how can i be able to resolve this issue? when I tried `SingleChildScrollView` then empty area("where there is no Widgets") of activity gone white. Is there any Widget that is missing or i made a mistake in my code?

**My Activity**

[image]

here is my **code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:marshal/Payment.dart';

import 'bottomnavigationbar.dart';

class Payment2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Payment2State createState() => _Payment2State();
}

class _Payment2State extends State<Payment2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PaymentButton = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.red,
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {
          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Paymentdone());
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
        },
        child: Text("Payment",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: style.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Payment"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:  Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            ),
            Text(
              "ENTER YOUR CARD DETAILS",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            ),
            Card(
              color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(),
                title: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "MasterCard",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '90 \u0024',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            ),
            Card(
              color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
              child: cardnumber(),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  //height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
                  color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: style,
                    maxLength: 5,
                    cursorColor: Colors.red,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'MM/YY',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                ),
                Container(
                  // height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.44,
                  color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: style,
                    maxLength: 3,
                    cursorColor: Colors.red,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'CVV',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100,
            ),
            PaymentButton,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
    );
  }

  Widget cardnumber() {
    return TextField(
      style: style,
      maxLength: 16,
      cursorColor: Colors.red,
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'XXXX XXXX XXXX 1234',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 0,
            style: BorderStyle.none,
          ),
        ),
        filled: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextStyle style =
      TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bottom overloaded by 213 pixels in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774252/bottom-overloaded-by-213-pixels-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a SingleChildScrollView is the right way to go.

in order to fix the issue you talked about, delete the color attribute from the container, and move it to the scaffold background color attribute:

```cs
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Payment"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            // the rest of the widgets...
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to your `Scaffold`

Comment: this will still cause the same problem when the app runs on smaller phones, and wont let him see the text fields when they are visualy behind the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Also you can wrap the child inside `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: this causes another issue, i mean the area of screen where there are no widgets have gone to white? meanwhile i am using container having background is black...

Comment: you can set containers height to screen height, that will cover all the remaining space..
also you can set scaffolds background color to black to resolve this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SingleChildScrollView` in `body`. To avoid white portion problem wrap it inside a `Stack`.

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
              ),
              Text(
                "ENTER YOUR CARD DETAILS",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              ),
              Card(
                color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(),
                  title: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "MasterCard",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '90 \u0024',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
              ),
              Card(
                color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
                child: cardnumber(),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    //height: 60,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
                    color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
                    child: TextField(
                      style: style,
                      maxLength: 5,
                      cursorColor: Colors.red,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'MM/YY',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    // height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.44,
                    color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
                    child: TextField(
                      style: style,
                      maxLength: 3,
                      cursorColor: Colors.red,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'CVV',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
              ),
              PaymentButton,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```